# Regex to find string with optional spaces

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate that a string has the values

```
edit=yes
edit = yes
edit= yes
edit =yes
edit=yesonce
edit = yesonce
edit= yesonce
edit =yesonce
```

What I have so far matches on `edit=yes` but nothing more. I think my optional spaces arguments are wrong but not sure how.

```
edit[/s]?=[/s]?[yes|yesonce]
```

Comment: Matcher for space is `\s` not `/s`

Comment: Also, are you sure *more* than one space would be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
edit\s?=\s?yes(once)?
```

Problems with your regex:

- Whitespace is `\s`, not `/s` - the escape character is backslash, not slash.
- You don't need `[]` around a single character (or escaped entity)
- `[yes|yesonce]` means any one of the characters `y e s | y e s o n c e`, not either `yes` or `yesonce`.
- You meant `(yes|yesonce)`, although that would always match `yes`, and not capture the `once` after the `yes` was matched. You could use `(yesonce|yes)` instead to avoid this, but..
- `yes(once)?` is simpler :)

If you intended to allow any number of spaces, rather than one or none, you need to replace the appropriate `?` symbols ("zero or one") with `*` ("any number including zero"):

```
edit\s*=\s*yes(once)?
```

Comment: :-) for `yes(once)?` and not `|`

Comment: Very likely; added a note about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :  `/edit\s*=\s*(yes|yesonce)/ig`

this will assure that  :

- edit word
- whitespaces or not
- =
- whitespaces or not
  *yes word

Comment: @bflemi3 yes. and searches globaly. ( sorry , too much javascript :-))

Answer (score -1):

You can use this regex, your slashes were reversed:

```
(edit[\s]?=[\s]?[yes|yesonce]+)
```

Test cases [here](http://rubular.com/r/NfsmAI6jMW)

Comment: Your `[yes|yesonce]+` is not doing what you think it is.. see my answer, and try the test case [`edit=seyconcce`](http://rubular.com/r/28uR2sC52t)